# Something wrong with adapter.... data is not Displaying from datasnapshot. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have linked a real-time firebase database with my android app. And now want to display data in recyclerview inside a fragment. I am getting my data in Log, but don't know something is wrong with my adapter.

I have been trying to look for any clue or idea on my problem. I am not getting any error in my Logcat. That's creating more confusion. 
Plus I am using real-time firebase for the first time, to add new skills.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        RecyclerView likes_recycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.likes_recyclerview);

        likesList = new ArrayList<>();
        showLikesData();
        likesAdapter = new BasedOnLikesAdapter(getContext(),likesList);
        likes_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        likes_recycler.setAdapter(likesAdapter);

        return view;

    }

    private void showLikesData() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query recentPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("business")
                .limitToFirst(10);

        recentPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("TEST", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1));
                    basedOnLikes = dataSnapshot1.child("value").getValue(BasedOnLikes.class);
                    likesList.add(basedOnLikes);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }
```

*My Adapter looks like this*

```
public class BasedOnLikesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BasedOnLikesAdapter.LikesVH> {

private List<BasedOnLikes> basedOnLikesArrayList;
Context context;


public BasedOnLikesAdapter(Context context, List<BasedOnLikes> based) {
    this.basedOnLikesArrayList = based;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BasedOnLikesAdapter.LikesVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.likes_home_cell, parent, false);

    return new LikesVH(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BasedOnLikesAdapter.LikesVH holder, int position) {
    BasedOnLikes item = basedOnLikesArrayList.get(position);
    //Log.e("Item",(basedOnLikesArrayList.get(position)).toString());
    holder.resName.setText(basedOnLikesArrayList.get(position).name);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return basedOnLikesArrayList.size();
}

public class LikesVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView resName;
    //private TextView resCuisine;
    private TextView resLocation;
    private TextView resReviewCount;
    private TextView city;
    private TextView state;
    private TextView is_open;

    public LikesVH(View view) {
        super(view);
        //resImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.res_img);
        resName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.res_title);
        //resCuisine = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.res_cuisine);
        resLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.res_location);
        resReviewCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratings_value);
        city = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.res_city);
        state = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.res_state);

    }
}
```

*My getter setter file*

```
public class BasedOnLikes {

public String  resImage;
public String name;
public String resCuisine;
public String address;
public int  review_count;
public String city;
public String state;
public String is_open;
public long  latitude;
public long  longitude;


public BasedOnLikes(String resName, String resLocation,
                    int  resReviewCount,String city, String is_open, long  latitude, long  longitude, String state) {
    //this.resImage = resImage;
    this.name = resName;
    //this.resCuisine = resCuisine;
    this.address = resLocation;
    this.review_count = resReviewCount;
    this.city = city;
    this.is_open = is_open;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.state = state;
}

public BasedOnLikes() {
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getIs_open() {
    return is_open;
}

public void setIs_open(String is_open) {
    this.is_open = is_open;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getResImage() {
    return resImage;
}

public void setResImage(String resImage) {
    this.resImage = resImage;
}

public int getReview_count() {
    return review_count;
}

public void setReview_count(int review_count) {
    this.review_count = review_count;
}

public long getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(long latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public long getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(long longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getResCuisine() {
    return resCuisine;
}

public void setResCuisine(String resCuisine) {
    this.resCuisine = resCuisine;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Just needed help in getting the data displayed in my recycler view.

Comment: You need to notify the adapter once you fill the list with data . Call `likesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in side `onDataChange` after for loop .

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: @ADM I tried using that... as its a fragment, i think notifyDataSetChanged() is not available